# how to use web speech api to insert its data in mongodb using ExpressJS and nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I want to insert data using webspeech api. every text which is recognised by webspeech api and coverted to text must be inserted to mongodb database. i want to use nodeJs here in javascript file also...what should be the solution??

here I am using express.js with node..

```
app.js
    const request = require('request')
    const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
    const YouTube = require('youtube-node')
    const yt = new YouTube()
    const config = require('./config')
    const ytApi = config.key
    const app = express()

    app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 3333))
    app.use(bodyParser.json())
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })) // support encoded bodies
    app.use(express.static('./dist'))
    yt.setKey(ytApi)

    app.get('/',(req, res) => {
      res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, './index.html'))
    })

    app.get('/2', (req, res) => {
      res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, './index2.html'))
    console.log("testing");

    })

    var callYt = (q ,callback) => {
      yt.search(q, 10, (err, result) => {
        if (err) throw error
        // yt.addParam('q', q);
        var vids = [] // Array of video ids to send to client
        for (var id in result.items) {
          if (result.items.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
            if (result.items[id].id.kind === 'youtube#video') {
              vids.push(result.items[id].id.videoId)
            }
          }
        }
        callback(vids[0]) // return the videos as callback
      })
    }

    app.get('/getVid', (req, res) => {
      var vid = req.query.vid
      callYt(vid, (data) => {
        res.json(data) // send video id
      })
    })

    app.get('/3', (req, res) => {
      res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, './index3.html'))
    })

    app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
      console.log(`Running app on localhost:${app.get('port')}...`)
    })
```

here is html file in which JS is used. how can i post text data to mongodb from here..

index.html

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Web Speech API Tutorial</title>
  <style>
    body {
      font-family: monospace;
      font-size: 22px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
  <body>
    <span id="speech"></span>
    <span id="interim"></span>
  </body>
  <script>


    function upgrade() {
      alert('Please use Google Chrome for best experience');
    }

    window.onload = function() {
      if (!(window.webkitSpeechRecognition) && !(window.speechRecognition)) {
        upgrade();
      } else {
        var recognizing,
        transcription = document.getElementById('speech'),
        interim_span = document.getElementById('interim');

        interim_span.style.opacity = '0.9';


        function reset() {
          recognizing = false;
          interim_span.innerHTML = '';
          transcription.innerHTML = '';
          speech.start();
        }

        var speech = new webkitSpeechRecognition() || speechRecognition();

        speech.continuous = true;
        speech.interimResults = true;
        speech.lang = 'en-US'; // check google web speech example source for more lanuages
        speech.start(); //enables recognition on default

        speech.onstart = function() {
            // When recognition begins
            recognizing = true;
        };

        speech.onresult = function(event) {
          // When recognition produces result
          var interim_transcript = '';
          var final_transcript = '';

          // main for loop for final and interim results
          for (var i = event.resultIndex; i < event.results.length; ++i) {
            if (event.results[i].isFinal) {
              final_transcript += event.results[i][0].transcript;
            } else {
              interim_transcript += event.results[i][0].transcript;
            }
          }
          transcription.innerHTML = final_transcript;
          interim_span.innerHTML = interim_transcript;
        };

        speech.onerror = function(event) {
            // Either 'No-speech' or 'Network connection error'
            console.error(event.error);
        };

        speech.onend = function() {
            // When recognition ends
            reset();
        };

      }
    };
  //    db.close();
  // });
  // });
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: what is the error?

Answer (score 1):

**Send a post request from frontend**

On the front end, in the index.html add a script to send a post request once the speech is done

```
for (var i = event.resultIndex; i < event.results.length; ++i) { 
            //I think this if statement is wrong and has to be rewritten,
            //but once you do, you can do the below
            if (event.results[i].isFinal) {
              final_transcript += event.results[i][0].transcript;
              //add it here
              let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
              xhr.open("POST", '/addSpeech', true) //assuming frontend and backend or on the same server
              xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
              xhr.send(JSON.stringify({
                  data: final_transcript
              }))
            } else {
              interim_transcript += event.results[i][0].transcript;
            }
          }
```

**Add mongoose and mongo to your app.js**

```
//add these two dependencies in your code then run npm i --save mongodb mongoose
const mongo = require('mongodb')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
//connect to your DB assuming mongod is already running
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/<name of db>')
const db = mongoose.connection
```

**Create a post route in your app.js to accept the text**

```
app.post('/addSpeech', (req,res)=>{
    let recievedData = req.body.speechOutput
    //depending on how you structure your db you'd do something along the lines
    //the collection name would be the one you choose when you structure your mongodb
    let newSpeech = new Speech({
         speech: recievedData
    })
    //save the data to your db
    newSpeech.save()
    //more code....
})
```